# How to copy one file to multiple folders?

Tags: macos, bash

Can I use the following for bash copying ONE file to Multiple folders within the same dir (IUHSD_Staff\A, B, C, D, E, F, etc.)

This is for Mac OSX in a .bash file - any help is appreciated!

```
cp ~/Documents/staff_folders.txt ~/Documents/IUHSD_Staff/Andrew.C
cp ~/Documents/staff_folders.txt ~/Documents/IUHSD_Staff/Andrew.D
cp ~/Documents/staff_folders.txt ~/Documents/IUHSD_Staff/Andrew.E
```

Comment: Did you try it? Didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
echo ~/Documents/IUHSD_Staff/Andrew.{A..F} | xargs -n1 -v cp ~/Documents/staff_folders.txt
```

`xargs` calls `cp` for every input line (`-n1`). `-v` gives a verbose output and can be omitted.